# sql server job set user mapping on different server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server job running on a SQL server 2016 instance (SQL1) that drops a database (SQL1_APPDB), and restores it from a production backup for testing purposes.

The SQL Job runs under a login (TESTLOGIN).

Since the database was dropped, its loses its user mapping under TESTLOGIN ,so I need to recreate it.

So in a job step, I execute the command:

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [TESTLOGIN]

That works successfully because the Database of the job step is SQL1_APPDB.

There is another SQL Server (SQL2) that has the login TESTLOGIN that has on it and a database (ANOTHERDB), and I need to add a user mapping to TESTLOGIN on SQL2 for ANOTHERDB.

I'm trying to do this from the same job as above running on SQL1 (NOT SQL2).

```
USE [SQL2].[ANOTHERDB]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [TESTLOGIN]
```

The step fails

I have a linked server set up between the two servers already
I can manually add the mapping through SSMS, but I'm trying to let this same job set up the user mapping.

Someone at work suggested that I deploy an SSIS package on SQL2 that could be kicked off from the job on SQL1 that would create the mapping.

Is there another way that this could be done from SQL1 in a job step?

Comment: Can you write the error you get when the step fails at ADD MEMBER [TESTLOGIN]

Comment: The SQL Agent account will be the account running the job. What kind of account is that? Domain? Local?

Comment: @WEI_DBA It is a Domain account

Comment: @PausePause the error is Executed as user: TESTLOGIN  Database 'SQL2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 911).  The step failed.

Comment: Just going off of the error alone, it doesn't seem like the problem is adding a new member role, it's creating the database after it gets dropped.

Comment: @PausePause - the database is restored in an earlier step. The ANOTHERDB is on a different server

Answer (score 0):

> TESTLOGIN Database 'SQL2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 911)

Such syntax is invalid:

```
USE [SQL2].[ANOTHERDB]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [TESTLOGIN]
```

If you really want to execute some code on a remote server it is possible via linked server this way:

```
EXECUTE ('USE [ANOTHERDB]; ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [TESTLOGIN]') AT SQL02
```

However, option `RPC OUT` has to be turned on it:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedServerName'
                              , @optname=N'rpc out'
                              , @optvalue=N'true'
```

Worth to mention, that while linked servers bring some flexibility, it is not always easy to keep them secure. Therefore, I would also join advice of using SSIS for orchestrations of all operations.

Comment: From the error though, is seems that SQL Server is interpreting the server name as the database name

Comment: @RickHodder, exactly, but this is expected since the linked server cannot be used in a `USE` statement